# XSLT converting string number with whitespace to number

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a problem with xslt trasformation.
How to convert number: "*2 402.83*" to numeber. Unfortunely when I use function `number(string(.))` I get NaN. I try to use replace function `number(replace(string(.), ' ', ''))`, but it returns nothing (exception in js: *Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.*).

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
   <cd number="1" price="2 402.82"/>
</catalog>
```

My xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <xsl:for-each select="@price">
        <span>                                      
          <xsl:value-of select="number(replace(string(.),' ', ''))" />
        </span>
      </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:for-each>                                
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `replace` function is not available in XSLT 1.0, use `translate` instead:

```
number(translate(string(.), ' ', ''))
```